# Upgrade db failed for 5:29

Tags: upgrade

I can't upgrade my database schema, I encounter error:

Found CiviCRM database version 5.29.alpha1.upgrade.
Found CiviCRM code version 5.29.0.
Cannot begin upgrade: The database indicates that an incomplete upgrade is pending. If you would like to resume, use --retry or --skip.

Retry or skip parameters doesn't change anything. How can I fix this db problem? I've tried some of the fix suggestions mostly about caches, from previous versions. Not helped.

It runs on Drupal8. Turns out the first problem occurs with:

Dropping SQL triggers...
Preparing upgrade...
Executing upgrade...
.......Error executing task: %s

[PEAR_Exception]
DB Error: no such table

Comment: Did you see anything in Civi logs?

Comment: Database check failed - the database looks to have been partially upgraded. You may want to reload the database with the backup and try the upgrade process again. -- message pops up with status notification.

My log viewer is empty. With debug open too...

Answer (score 2):

When I had a similar problem under WordPress moving from 5.25 to 5.28 I discovered that the database couldn't manage the update while logging was enabled. Try disabling it (CiviCRM->Administer->System Settings->Logging) and trying again. You may need to return to a backup first.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I've cleared cache and also found the partial upgrade information in database and deleted that too. It still looks for a log file which is missing but I can't find how it looks which file to look, database doesn't have that information anymore...